# Is it good design to have more than 100 wcf service classes in the project

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, wcf

[EDIT]
In more generic terms, If , we have high no. of entities (tables) which needs to have CRUD operations supported over WCF (both TCP and HTTP) , what is the best approach for solution design.
[EDIT END]

We have around 300 tables in the database and we have to provide crud operations for all these tables. We are trying to implement using entity framework and repository pattern as described in the link - http://blog.longle.net/2013/05/11/genericizing-the-unit-of-work-pattern-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-in-mvc/

and codeplex project 
http://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/documentation

It has following IService interface and it's implementation where I can pass Entity object and do not have to implement methods manually.

```
public interface IService<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
{
    [OperationContract]
    TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues);     
   [OperationContract]
    IQueryable<TEntity> SelectQuery(string query, params object[] parameters);
       [OperationContract]
    void Insert(TEntity entity);
       [OperationContract]
    void InsertRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
       [OperationContract]
    void InsertGraph(TEntity entity);
       [OperationContract]
    void InsertGraphRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
       [OperationContract]
    void Update(TEntity entity);
       [OperationContract(Name="DeleteByID")]
    void Delete(object id);
       [OperationContract]
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
       [OperationContract]
       List<TEntity> Query();
       [OperationContract(Name="QueryEntity")]
       List<TEntity> Query(IQueryObject<TEntity> queryObject);   
}
```

As WCF does not support generics, I have to create one interface and one class implementing that interface. For Employee entity

`[ServiceContract] public interface IEmployeeService : IService<Employee>{}
    class EmployeeService : Service<Employee>, IEmployeeService{}`

Question is to add crud operations for all these , I will have to create around 300 such service interfaces and consume it in the WPF client application. Is it correct design approach ? What other options are available.

Note :- We have to support both HTTP and TCP protocols through WCF.

Comment: In your case, if you really need CRUD, why not simply use a REST service and use oData to query? Then you get this out of the box.

Comment: REST and oData is not supported over TCP. That's why I am trying to find other approaches.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and +1 for asking an interesting question. However, can you please edit it to make it less subjective, as subjective questions are off topic for this website and are likely to be closed and/or deleted by the community. Please see the [Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) page from the Stack Overflow Help Center for more information on this.

Comment: This feels like a horrific design. You seriously need direct CRUD on 300 tables? Isn't there any layer of abstraction or business logic over them?

Comment: I also does not feel, this is the best approach but not able to find alternate solution. There are around 500 entities (Tables) in the application. I can group them into around 300 relevant groups. There are many reference tables which user wants to maintain.

Comment: Then maybe drop the TCP requirement. Do you really need that?

Comment: WCF should expose the business services, not the database itself. You'd be better off connecting to the database directly, rather than what you are trying to do now. A bad design can't be fixed by such workarounds.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos user has requirement of maintaining 100 tables , where they should be able to perform CRUD operations over the internet/intranet. What is the solution for this ? I am not sure if, exposing database over internet was the serious suggestion.

Comment: If you have to expose CRUD over the internet, web API/REST is a good alternative. You can even use projection to avoid your database to be exposed. I'm not sure why TCP is such a strong requirement though.